# Azure hosted WCF azure active directory authentication returns 404

Tags: wcf, azure, http-status-code-404, azure-active-directory

I'm new to WCF. I created WCF method that returns file. I deployed it to azure App Service and it worked when i called it like this

```
https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/myService.svc/MyMethod?MyParam=MyValue
```

Than i turned on Azure active directory authentication for azure App Service and now i get 404 error. But authentication against AAD works - i get redirected to login page if i'm not singed in user.

I tried searching SO and google and i can't figure out what i'm doing wrong or if it is just not possible to set up this way with WCF.

Web config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceWebBindingName" transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >
          <readerQuotas  maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DefaultRestServiceBehavior">
          <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" defaultBodyStyle="Wrapped" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="My.App.Service">
        <endpoint address="myService.svc"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="ServiceWebBindingName"
              behaviorConfiguration="DefaultRestServiceBehavior"
              name="FileManagerServiceEndpoint"
              contract="My.App.IService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
        preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: did you check this post that talks about wcf + AAD integration https://dzone.com/articles/exercise-3-securing-wcf

Comment: I did, in the article, they are not using azure hosting with set up authentication, but doing everything in code if i understood it correctly.

Comment: yea,the authentication part is done in the code..

Comment: i see that u r doing webhttpbinding and trying to use http/restful in wcf. if you want restful service it is better to use web api. can u link to the article based on which you setup the wcf with AAD?

Comment: Not really any article, i just created WCF service, deployed it and then set up authentization using this https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-value-prop-what-is/ functionality in Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found out i did not notice, that my original service url was

```
http://myapp.azurewebsites.net/myService.svc/MyMethod?MyParam=MyValue
```

and one that i was redirected to after adding azure ad authentication was

```
https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/myService.svc/MyMethod?MyParam=MyValue
```

So redirect points to **HTTPS** and not HTTP.

It is probably possible to set azure ad application not enforce HTTPS traffic, however in spirit of security and to avoid possible IE zone switching issues I added HTTPS transport to my WCF binding in web.config. Here is great example how to do it [How to enable HTTPS on WCF RESTful Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246633/how-to-enable-https-on-wcf-restful-service) and it now works flawlessly.