# WCF Method returns 400 Bad Request on Production

Tags: wcf, axios, wcf-binding

Methods of WCF REST Service are working with C# WCFClient against Production-Server.
They are also working in Dev-Environment on localhost.
The Service and the wsdl are ok from browser access on production also.

[Access to svc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9689E.png)

[Access to wsdl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HClUW.png)

**But** when I access any method from the service on Production-Server, 400 Bad Request will be returned.
IIS-log shows also 400: GET /WCD/WCF.svc/GetNextGuestNumber - 443 -  Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/83.0.4103.61+Safari/537.36 https://www.DS.XXX.com/qa/dLobby **400** 0 0 46

Here is my web.config from Production:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>  
    <appSettings>
      <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
      <add key="WBCCNN" value="PQkSAXkRXNsanbA5xK1KBZZqu+oxrJbssQlEiM1Fi+N2Vnz0F5QfAetqILb0QeLwlF7jMZ57k9J8sIlAJ1TRjtfgwh0V88Q2Kl/20Cny2WCTawWyDSECKg=="/>
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>  
      <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    </system.web>  
    <system.serviceModel>  
      <services>  
        <service name="DS.XXX.Services.WCF" behaviorConfiguration="DSServiceBehavior">  
          <endpoint address=""  
              binding="basicHttpBinding"  
              bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"  
              contract="DS.XXX.Services.IWCF"/>  
          <endpoint address="mex"  
              binding="mexHttpsBinding"  
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />  
        </service>  
      </services>  
      <bindings>  
        <basicHttpBinding>  
          <binding name="secureHttpBinding">  
            <security mode="Transport"> 
            </security>  
          </binding>  
        </basicHttpBinding>  
      </bindings>  
      <behaviors>  
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="DSServiceBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpsGetUrl="" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          </behavior> 
        </serviceBehaviors>  
      </behaviors>  
      <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />  
    </system.serviceModel>  
    <system.webServer>  
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>  
    </system.webServer>  
  </configuration>
```

The methods are called from a REACT JS App with Axios

```
const res = await API.get("/GetNextGuestNumber");
```

The API from Axios is configured like so:

```
import axios from "axios";
import global from "../config";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: global.webServicesUrl,
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
});
```

As the service is working on dev and the svc and the wsdl is reachable on prod, it must be something with the binding and endpoint configuration?

I am using a Certificate from a third party vendor which is working fine also.
I don't see it. Any help is appreciated. If you need any more details, pleas let me know.

Env.: Windows Server 2016, IIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in the binding. You should use webhttpbinding to build the WCF REST Service, but I see in the configuration file that you used basichttpbinding.In this case, when you use JS to access the service, you will receive 400 errors.

```
        <services>
        <service name="Demo_rest_IIS.Service1"
                 behaviorConfiguration="UserServiceBehavior">
            <endpoint address=""
                      binding="webHttpBinding"
                      contract="Demo_rest_IIS.IService1"
                      behaviorConfiguration="ESEndPointBehavior" bindingConfiguration="bind"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ESEndPointBehavior">
                <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="UserServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

This is the configuration file of WCF rest service that I deployed in IIS.

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "user/?name={name}",RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Result GetUserData(string name);
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "user", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Result PostUserData(UserData user);
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "user", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Result PutUserData(UserData user);
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", UriTemplate = "user", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Result DeleteUserData(UserData user);
```

This is the interface of the service.In the configuration file, I set the value of helpenabled to true. After deploying the service, we use the help document to see how to access it.

[image]

This is the help document for the service.

For more information about WCF REST Service, please refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-web-http-programming-model

Comment: You are pointing to http but I am using https. But anyway, your hint regarding webHttpBinding pointed me to the right direction. First I got 500 with that setting but with adding a behaviorConfiguration to my endpoint (<webHttp/>) I now got it working. Thanks. Credits also to Derek W from this Post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246633/how-to-enable-https-on-wcf-restful-service